# Second series not displaying in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, python, django, highcharts

I am trying to create a graph to display performance of a system. My issue is that Higcharts, for some reason, won't recognize that I have more than one series. The first series displays perfectly, however the second is no where to be seen.
I am using Django 1.8 to loop the data from dictionaries.

My series code:

```
series: [
    {% for ID, run in attDict.items|sort %}
    {
        yAxis: 0,
        id: "Run" + {{forloop.counter}},
        name: "RunID " + {{ID}},
        color: getLineColor({{ID}}),
        data: {{run}},
        marker: {
            fillColor: getFillColor({{forloop.counter}}),
        },
        visible: false
        },
    {% endfor %}

    {% for key, task in TaskE.items|sort %}
    {
        yAxis: 1,
        id: "during",
        linkedTo: "Run" + {{forloop.counter}},
        name: "Duringtask for run " + {{key}}
        type: 'area',
        color: '#12e000',
        fillOpacity: 0.3,
        data: {{task}},
        visible: fasle
        }{% if forloop.last %}{% else %},{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    ]
```

The output look like this:

```
series: [
    {
        yAxis: 0,
        id: "Run" + 1,
        name: "RunID " + 250,
        color: getLineColor(250),
        data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 33, 27, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 83, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        marker: {
            fillColor: getFillColor(1),
        },
        visible: false
    },

    {
        yAxis: 0,
        id: "Run" + 2,
        name: "RunID " + 256,
        color: getLineColor(256),
        data: [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        marker: {
            fillColor: getFillColor(2),
        },
        visible: false
    },

    {
        yAxis: 0,
        id: "Run" + 3,
        name: "RunID " + 257,
        color: getLineColor(257),
        data: [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        marker: {
            fillColor: getFillColor(3),
        },
        visible: false
    },

    {
        yAxis: 0,
        id: "Run" + 4,
        name: "RunID " + 265,
        color: getLineColor(265),
        data: [83, 0, 101, 0, 0, 96, 0],
        marker: {
            fillColor: getFillColor(4),
        },
        visible: false
    },

    {
        yAxis: 0,
        id: "Run" + 5,
        name: "RunID " + 295,
        color: getLineColor(295),
        data: [14, 3, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 70, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 83, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 52, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 45, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 77, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 67, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 88, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 3, 0, 58, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        marker: {
            fillColor: getFillColor(5),
        },
        visible: false
    },

    {
        yAxis: 0,
        id: "Run" + 6,
        name: "RunID " + 296,
        color: getLineColor(296),
        data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 116, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 28, 15],
        marker: {
            fillColor: getFillColor(6),
        },
        visible: false
    },
]
```

Comment: why did you set visible: false for the series?, i'm surprise it's showing any of the series at all

Comment: Visible what set to false only to hide the series upon first loading the graph. Visible or not, the series should be displayed in the legend where it can be toggled on or off http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.visible

Comment: Your problem is not recreatable - the config without getFillColor/getLineColor works correctly. Can you adjust the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tru0psqL/1/ - you can see that the series are hidden and their visibility can be toggled.

Comment: @morganfree sorry, it appears that I haven't been very clear. All of the data from the first loop is being displayed correctly, as is the case in the fiddle. It is the second loop that is meant to display a true or false (1 or 0) value that won't appear. The first loop works.

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly telling the chart not to show the series in the legend by using this:

```
linkedTo: "Run" + {{forloop.counter}}
```

> When two series are linked, only the first one appears in the legend.
>   Toggling the visibility of this also toggles the linked series.

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.linkedTo

Remove the `linkedTo` property from the second loop, and it should work fine.

Comment: Tried and failed. linkedTo has a purpose. I am using it to show when a task is running. What I am trying to do is display a run along with the linked series. so when you display a run, the during task information is also shown. I have used this method in another very similar graph. The issue is that no data from the second loop is being shown.

Comment: 1) "Tried and failed" in what way? Be specific. 2) linkedTo will hide the series from the legend, so whether or not it has a purpose, it is causing the behavior you describe, and it's meant to.

Comment: Going back to the original post, you appear to show the output from the first loop, but not from the second. Is nothing being output from the second loop at all? If that's the case, then we don't need to look at the chart code at all. If not, show us the output.

Comment: I removed the linkedTo property and nothing changed. linkedTo simply means that if i want to view the data from the second loop, I need to click on an legend item to show the run. The linkedTo property should then, in theory show the linked data also. If you look at the code above, you can see that in the output, there simply is no sign of the series from the second loop. What is show above is the entire snippet of Series[ ]

Comment: OK, so that's an entirely different problem than "the chart doesn't show the series". The problem appears to be that the loop doesn't output anything. You'll need to check the inputs to your loop, and make sure they contain what's expected, and test the loop separately from the chart to find why it is not outputting anything.

Comment: I have done this several times. I am able to loop out all data exactly as expected at the backend aswell as directly onto the webpage. Edit: Thank you for your patience, this is my first post on SO.

Comment: I don't know anything about python or django, but there must be some kind of check that you can insert in your loop to output the counter, or some other error checking, to make sure 1) the loop as actually running and 2) what information it is finding as it loops.  Also, make sure you've checked for any javascript errors in the console.

Comment: I'm unsure if there's is a way to debug the graph code itself. I can however print the data by doing essentially the same looping technique.                                                                                                      {% for key, task in taskE.items|sort %}
        {{key}}
        {{task}}                                                                                              {% endfor %}                                                                                                                 This gives me the expected output. There are also no JS errors.